# "He was (to be) called All of you"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> ‘There is one important thing which we must not forget,’ he said as
> they flew on their way. ‘When people are invited to a great feast like
> this, they take new names for the occasion. Our hosts in the sky will
> expect us to honor this age-old custom.’
>
> ‘‘None of the birds had heard of this custom but they knew that
> Tortoise, in spite of his failings in other directions, was a
> widely-traveled man who knew the customs of different peoples. And so
> they each took a new name. When they had all taken, Tortoise also took
> one. **He was to be called All of you**.

Is **to be** necessary here? Is there going to be a difference if we take out **to be**?

Answer (score 1):

*He was called X* suggests that X was his real name. This is apparently a different name that he is taking on just for the occasion, so he was going *to be* known by it at the feast.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

“He was to be called...” means that the new name applies from this point forward.

“He was called...” means the name was used in the past.

Very different.

Comment: Thank you very much.